# Error when reading pickle file - permission error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pickle, permission-denied

I'm trying to read a pickle file.

```
df= pd.read_pickle(r'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\pickle_file')

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\pickle_file'
```

I have no other instances of python running. It's my first time importing the pickle file. What causes this issue?

Comment: Could it be a problem of path?

Comment: Try running the python script as an admin in windows envs or using sudo in linux envs.